# Определение одного конкретного объекта на фоне остальных оператором Кэнни OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Привет, использую оператор Кэнни, хочу определить конкретный объект на фоне остальных. При отрисовки контуров, изначально выдается мешанина со всего, чего только можно. Подскажите как выделить конкретный, интересующий меня объект, и проигнорировать остальные.

[image: Скриншот результата работы оператора Кэнни]

На скриншоте видно, что оператор находит все, что может.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по скриншоту, объектом интереса является персона перед камерой. В таком случае контурный анализ никак не поможет в решении задачи. Слишком идеальными должны быть условия, чтобы контурные линии полностью опоясывали объект. А поскольку последний находится в естественной среде, то и результат детекции соответствующий.

Если задача требует осуществлять детекцию лица в кадре, то обратите внимание на классификатор каскада (Хаара или классификатор на локальных бинарных шаблонах - `LBP`). В случае с произвольным объектом можно воспользоваться тем же методом, но произведя предварительно обучение собственного классификатора.

Comment: Да, про каскады Хаара, я в курсе, но мне интересно, как эту проблему можно решить математическим путем.

Comment: @asda111sd , ну вот когда придумают такой оператор, что будет корректно с точки зрения человека находить контуры объектов в естественной среде, то это несомненно станет прорывом в области компьютерного зрения. Самое сильное преимущество контурного анализа по сравнению с другими подходами - это скорость, но оно существенно лишь когда контуры уже обнаружены, а не до.

Comment: А как тогда правильно заранее задать объект сравнения для после найденных контуров?